# Are there any non-selenium based tools for Automation testing?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, tools

I'm aware of automation tools like- Selenium, Appium, Selendroid.

Is there any other tool available in the market which is used for automation testing outside of the selenium group?

Comment: What is automation testing? Is that a process of verifying whether an automated script works fine? Or maybe you meant test automation?

Comment: Test automation is more than test execution. See article of James Bach (p. 2) on what else can be automated: http://www.satisfice.com/articles/agileauto-paper.pdf.

Comment: You listed tools for testing Web applications. Is that a domain of your interest? There are other types of applications and systems to test in the world.

Comment: Retitled and redid content to try and make this a useful question.  I  moved it a little away form the original content which did not meet our format for suitable questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find [MITM proxies](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) and [Mocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking)/[Stubbing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463278/what-is-a-stub) to be the most advanced pieces of Technology in Automated Checking.

By using these, it makes it far easier to:

1. Create repeatable, consistent checks
2. Decrease overall execution speed
3. Segregate the application into logical pieces
4. Record executed manual tests

But for the real answer, QA's knowledge and senses is the most advanced tool we have. The ability to intuitively detect an issue. The 'this just doesn't feel right to me' instinct that we develop that causes us to push deeper.

Answer (score 4):

The most recent developments that I have observed are:

1. Running tests in the cloud.  Companies like [Sauce Labs](http://www.saucelabs.com) and [Browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com) are leaders here.  There are many advantages to this, from the number of devices being tested to the number of parallels servers that can be used.
2. Writing UI tests using UI tools.  Products such as [Ghostinspector](http://www.ghostinspector.com), [heliumhq](http://heliumhq.com/) and [TestCafe](http://testcafe.devexpress.com/) are starting to become available and allow you to build test cases using a web GUI.
3. Increasing use of mocking and stubbing of components such as database and other services / micro-services, as noted by Paul Muir (+1) so that tests can run in milliseconds instead of seconds and minutes.  A well-stubbed test suite of hundreds of (non-ui) tests should run in 5-10 mins and not just grow to unwieldy over time.  This takes work.
4. Agile.  As Agile is now a leading approach, automation specialist needs to develop automation within the agile process.  This is a huge topic on its own.
5. Tools like jmeter for performance testing
6. Ruby and rspec provide the framework that capybara runs within and they are powerful frameworks in their own right and can be used flexibly in various situations.

Comment: Yes, really the tools like Sauce Labs are now a days famous testing tool. 
Thanks @Michael
Any other optional tools used for Web & mobile testing?